# Can't build HomeBridge from open-peer2peer-mail open source project

Tags: email, open-source

Who can help me with open-peer2peer-email project at [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-peer2peer-email/?source=directory)? I downloaded HomeBridge.zip. It looks like it hardcore but I don't see any Makefile in it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that HomeBridge sub project is actually Qt core project. You can use qmake to build it:

```
> qmake HomeBridge.pro
```